# Crear un archivo .bin en java

Tags: java

necesito crear un archivo con extensión .bin en JAVA, he buscado algún ejemplo pero aún no he encontrado alguna información.

Agradecería cualquier información.

Gracias, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta especificarlo con la extension `.bin` y tendras un archivo bin:

```
File binFile = new File("c:/mi_archivo.bin");

if(!binFile.exists())
{
   binFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Si te diriges al `c:/` encontras el archivo `bin`.

Comment: La extencion no define un archivo, lo que define un archivo es su contenido. Aunque tenga `.bin` ese es un archivo vacio hasta que se llene con alguna clase de contenido, que bien puede ser un audio, un texto, una imagen... Un archivo `.jpg` puede ser un archivo de texto y no una imagen.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, no tenia muy bien el concepto, pero con lo que comentas me quedó claro ya que el archivo .bin guardaré objetos.